# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message "Не найден класс"

Tags: php

Выдает:

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅ РєР»Р°СЃСЃ Modules\Profile\Models\Exception РІ С„Р°Р№Р»Рµ C:\inetpub\conferences\Modules\Profile\Models\Exception.php' in C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Autoloader.php:30
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Autoloader::loadClass('Modules\Profile...')
#1 C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Tools\HighriseAPI.php(130): spl_autoload_call('Modules\Profile...')
#2 C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Tools\HighriseAPI.php(1763): Modules\Profile\HighriseAPI->checkForErrors('Person', 201)
#3 C:\inetpub\conferences\Modules\Profile\Profile.php(381): Modules\Profile\HighrisePerson->save()
#4 C:\inetpub\conferences\Modules\Registration\Registration.php(54): Modules\Profile\Profile->addHR('thekoveshnikov@...', Array)
#5 C:\inetpub\conferences\Application\controllers\c_registration.php(10): Modules\Registration\Registration->complete('64', '1c6ccfc497f6745...')
#6 C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Kernel\BaseController.php(28): Application\Controller->complete()
#7 C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Ke in C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Autoloader.php on line 30
```

не знаю как исправить. Кто, что может подсказать?

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что выполняет код. Приложите кусок кода, а то с такой простыней немного сложновато понять что происходит. Какой фреймворк используете?

Comment: Кодировку нормальную ошибки можно выложить-то?

Comment: Скорей всего перевод такой - невозможно выполнить операцию
Попробуйте обернуть код в try catch

Answer (score 2):

Не с `PHP` проблема, а с загрузкой класса.
Расшифровываю: `"Не найден класс Modules\Profile\Models\Exception в файле C:\inetpub\conferences\Modules\Profile\Models\Exception.php"`

Возможно у вас там неправильно написано имя класса.

Answer (score 2):

Вот эта строчка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅ РєР»Р°СЃСЃ Modules\Profile\Models\Exception РІ С„Р°Р№Р»Рµ C:\inetpub\conferences\Modules\Profile\Models\Exception.php' in C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Autoloader.php:30
```

**Означает**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Не найден класс Modules\Profile\Models\Exception в файле C:\inetpub\conferences\Modules\Profile\Models\Exception.php' in C:\inetpub\conferences\VZ\Autoloader.php:30
```

**Варианты**:

1. Правильно укажите путь к файлу / классу
2. Напишите этот класс